# Add connection point bug?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, atl

Today I had to pass the ATL Tutorial from MSDN but met a problem. Unfortunately, I'm not a real C++ developer and can't do it myself.

In [Step 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h7xedd1.aspx) when I add connection point, wizard create _IPolyCtrlEvents_CP.H but it doesn't implement the Fire_ClickIn and Fire_ClickOut methods. How I can implement them?

I'm using VS2010.

Thanks for your advises :)

Comment: Already found an answer. In VS2010 Samples. But as for me this is definitely something wrong with Studio's Add Connection point Wizard. :(

Comment: What did you do to fix it? Having the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

I am also learning ATL programming and meet the problem too.
It is not a connection point bug.
In the connection point wizard, you should select "available type libraries" to be "PolygonLib<1.0>". Defaultly, it is "imbeded IDL".

Answer (score 2):

Workaround in vs2012: Within 'Implementing a Connection Point' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7zd1wd1.aspx

Before step 3:

3.pre (DO NOT SELECT 'Embedded IDL' under 'Available type libraries', select project's typelib instead)

If we choose typelib, the Fire_* methods will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. Make sure you add the connection point methods by right-clicking on the `_IxxxEvents` under the xxxLib class in class view. You will see the method added to the dispinterface `_IxxxEvents` ... methods: section. If the method code stub was actually created elsewhere in the code, the event method was added incorrectly and `Fire_` method will not be generated.

Answer (score 0):

But I met a different situation. I added new methods in XXXLib/IXXXEvent, and they were automatically added in XXX.idl with tag "dispinterface *IPolyCtlEvents". But after I add methods as the MSDN guide say, the Fire* method are not added to _xxxEvent_CP.H. So I add new methods in IXXXEvent instead of XXXLib/IXXXEvent, and the problem is solved.